# SQLAlchemy distinct ignoring order_by

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to run a query from my flask application using SQLAlchemy where I order the results by the timestamp in descending order. From the returned order I want to pull the distinct sender_id's. Unfortunately distinct ignores my requested order_by and pulls the data from the standard table layout.

```
messagesReceived = Message.query.filter_by(recipient_id=user_id).order_by(Message.timestamp.desc()).group_by(Message.sender_id).distinct()
```

I'm still new to SQLAlchemy and through the tutorials and lessons I have done I haven't encountered this, I tried googling but I don't think I am phrasing it correctly to get the answer. I'm currently trying to wrap my head around sub-queries as I think that might be a way to make it work, but asking here in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL query is illogical. You select the entire message, but group by `person_id`. Unless it is unique, it is indeterminate which row the values are selected from for the group row. ORDER BY is logically performed after GROUP BY, and since `timestamp` is now indeterminate, so is the resulting order. Some SQL DBMS do not even allow such a query to run, as it is not allowed by the SQL standard.

To fetch distinct `sender_id`s ordered by their latest `timestamp` per `sender_id` do

```
messagesReceived = db.session.query(Message.sender_id).\
    filter_by(recipient_id=user_id).\
    group_by(Message.sender_id).\
    order_by(db.func.max(Message.timestamp))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PostgreSQL,

```
messagesReceived = Message.query.filter_by(recipient_id=user_id).order_by(Message.sender_id.asc(), Message.timestamp.desc()).distinct(Message.sender_id).all()
```

There may not be a need to group by `sender_id`. Distinct can also be applied at the Query level (affects the entire query, not just the column), as described [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html?highlight=distinct#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.distinct), so the order_by needs the sender_id, post which, the distinct can be applied on a specific column.

This may be specific to PostgreSQL, however, so if you're using another DB, I would recommend the `distinct` expression as outlined [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=distinct).

> from sqlalchemy import distinct, func
> stmt = select([func.count(distinct(users_table.c.name))])